# How to deploy Node/Express server with AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy a simple server that sends out emails from a contact form I have on an angular 2 front end.

I am trying to get the server working on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, but I keep getting a 'severe' health status error when I try to upload it and get it going. It works fine on my localhost environment, though.

Am I missing something like a "start" script or? Do I need to do something with my port? This is my first node/express server, so I'm probably missing something silly.

Here is my server.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var mg = require('nodemailer-mailgun-transport');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.all("/*", function(req, res, next){
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');
  next();
});

//api key and domain for mailgun
var auth = {
  auth: {
    api_key: 'key',
    domain: 'sandbox.mailgun.org'
  }
}

//send email from angular 2 with nodemailer here
app.post('/contact-form-submit', function(req, res) {

    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(mg(auth));

    var mailOptions = {
        from: 'postmaster@.mailgun.org',
        to: 'emailname@email.com',
        subject: ' Form Submission',
        text: ' Name: ' + req.body.name + ' Email: ' + req.body.email + ' Message: ' + req.body.message + ' Jobs: ' + req.body.jobs,
        html: '<p>You have a new form submission: </p><br><ul><li>Name: ' + req.body.name + '</li><li>Email: ' + req.body.email + '</li><li>Jobs: ' + req.body.jobs + '</li><li>Message: ' + req.body.message + '</li></ul>' 
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            res.redirect('/');
        } else {
            console.log('Message sent.');
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    })

});

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Express started on port 3000');
});
```

And here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "project-name-here",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "express": "^4.15.4",
    "nodemailer": "^4.0.1",
    "nodemailer-mailgun-transport": "^1.3.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you figure out how to bundle the dist and server-dist? I cant find instruction anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You Need to add in package.json file start script configuration

```
{
  "name": "project-name-here",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "express": "^4.15.4",
    "nodemailer": "^4.0.1",
    "nodemailer-mailgun-transport": "^1.3.5"
  }
}
```